# problem in validate some fields in blazor

Tags: c#, validation, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I want to validate some fields in blazor I am not able to do it, plz help

**Error message**

System.InvalidOperationException: DataAnnotationsValidator requires a cascading parameter of type EditContext. For example, you can use DataAnnotationsValidator inside an EditForm.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.DataAnnotationsValidator.OnInitialized()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()

[Code pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gra5m.png)

Comment: You are using components that are designed to work within a `<EditForm>` not `<form>`. You should paste your code not an image of your code.

Comment: Hi Ashish, could you confirm if my response resolves your issue?

Answer (score 2):

you need to use a code structure like this:

```
<EditForm Model="viewModel" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <ValidationSummary />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
<LabelText For="(() => viewModel.FirstName)" class="control-label" />
                            <InputText @bind-Value="viewModel.FirstName" id="FirstName" readonly="@viewModel.ReadonlyData" class="form-control" />
                            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => viewModel.FirstName)" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</EditForm>
```